# Identity Server 4 support for Secure Cipher Suites

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

We are currently using Identity Server 3 and want to upgrade to Identity Server 4.

We recently did a Penetration Test for a large client of ours and they picked up that we allowed the TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cypher suite. Which is an insecure Cipher Suite with known vulnerabilities.
When we disallowed it, then Identity Server 3 stopped working.

Is there a way to get IdentityServer3 to work when disabling this cipher suite?
Our certificate is correct and meets the requirements.

Will Identity Server 4 work if we disallow it? Or will it give the same problem.
The error we got was the following:
The Client and Server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

Comment: This is not an IdentityServer error message - it comes from Katana or IIS - ask Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, as indicated by leastprivilege, it was a microsoft issue.
When using .net4.5 and below they do not use tls1.2 by default and always revert to tls1.1. 
So you if you are using .net4.5 then you need to tell it to use tls1.2 by setting the registry settings indicated by this article:
https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Troubleshooting/KB/KB01625

Once I configured those registry settings, then everything worked fine using tls1.2.